# How to apply jQuery shadow function to multiple elements with the same class name when scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched extensively for a solution to this but with no luck. I have a horizontal scroller that adds a shadow to each side of the scrollable div to indicate whether there is more content or not. My problem is that I have multiple divs and tables on the same page with the same class name (I did not build this page so cant assign unique class names. I need to know how to add some sort of each/loop function to my code so that the function applies to each element individually. I have set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usu4enev/) with my code to better explain what I mean, as it's quite difficult to explain, but I'm sure that this will clarify what I'm asking. At present I have 3 scrolling divs, but whether I scroll the first, second or third one, the shadows are only applied to the first. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The code i currently have is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.data-holder').scroll(function() {
    var scrollValue = $(this).scrollLeft();

    if (scrollValue == 0) {
      $("#shadowtop").fadeOut(200);
    } else if (scrollValue == ($(this).get(0).scrollWidth - $(this).width())) {
      $("#shadowbottom").fadeOut(200);
    } else {
      $("#shadowtop").fadeIn(200);
      $("#shadowbottom").fadeIn(200);
    }
  });
  var scrollValue = $('.data-holder').scrollLeft();
  if (scrollValue < ($('.data-holder').get(0).scrollWidth - $('.data-holder').width())) {
    $("#shadowbottom").show();
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".data-holder").smoothTouchScroll({
    continuousScrolling: true
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.data-holder {
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#shadowtop,
#shadowbottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
  background-size: 100% 0;
}
#shadowtop {
  left: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at 0 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
}
#shadowbottom {
  right: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at 100% 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
}
.block {
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: beige;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="data-holder">
    <div id="shadowtop"></div>
    <div id="shadowbottom"></div>
    <div class="block">content 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="data-holder">
    <div id="shadowtop"></div>
    <div id="shadowbottom"></div>
    <div class="block">content 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="data-holder">
    <div id="shadowtop"></div>
    <div id="shadowbottom"></div>
    <div class="block">content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issues/Suggestions:**

1. You're having duplicate `id`s in your markup, `id`s **must** be *unique*. Use it as *class*, instead of `id`.
2. You'll need to use the element that is in the current context to show correct shadow to the current element that is being scrolled. For this, I've used the context selector. Ex: `$(".shadowtop", this)`, this will select the element having class `shadowtop` and which is inside the `this` element.
3. The function `smoothTouchScroll` was giving error since you haven't included the respective plugin file, so for the demo purpose I've removed it.
4. To show the right shadow by default, use `display: block;` for the `.shadowbottom` class in CSS.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/usu4enev/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.data-holder').scroll(function() {
    var scrollValue = $(this).scrollLeft();

    if (scrollValue == 0) {
      $(".shadowtop", this).fadeOut(200);
    } else if (scrollValue == ($(this).get(0).scrollWidth - $(this).width())) {
      $(".shadowbottom", this).fadeOut(200);
    } else {
      $(".shadowtop", this).fadeIn(200);
      $(".shadowbottom", this).fadeIn(200);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.data-holder {
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.shadowtop,
.shadowbottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
  background-size: 100% 0;
}
.shadowtop {
  left: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at 0 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
}
.shadowbottom {
  right: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at 100% 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 0 100%;
  display: block;
}
.block {
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: beige;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="data-holder">
    <div class="shadowtop"></div>
    <div class="shadowbottom"></div>
    <div class="block">content 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="data-holder">
    <div class="shadowtop"></div>
    <div class="shadowbottom"></div>
    <div class="block">content 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="data-holder">
    <div class="shadowtop"></div>
    <div class="shadowbottom"></div>
    <div class="block">content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. This is almost perfect. The only remaining problem is as follows. I need it to detect if the container has scrollable content (it's for mobile), and if so to add the right shadow to the scrollable containers on load. I tried adding something like the following to the code but it doesn't work: 

$('.scroll-container').each(function(){
    if ($(".scroll-container").prop('scrollWidth') > $(".scroll-container").width() ) {
    var shadowRight = $(this).find(".shadow-right");
     shadowRight.show();
    }

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion to, for default, use display: block; for the .shadowbottom class in CSS. The only problem with this is that it will then show the shadows whether the divs scroll or not. I need them added by default only if the divs are scrollable. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript as following, it should work.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.data-holder').each(function() {
        //hold the shadowTop and shadowBottom in a reference so that you don't make query every time
        var shadowTop = $(this).find("#shadowtop"),
            shadowBottom = $(this).find("#shadowbottom");
        var scrollValue = $(this).scrollLeft();

        //check initiall scroll value and show the shadows accordingly
        if (scrollValue < ($(this).get(0).scrollWidth - $(this).width())) {
            shadowBottom.show();
        }
        $(this).scroll(function() {
            var scrollValue = $(this).scrollLeft();
            var shadowTop = $(this).find("#shadowtop"),
                shadowBottom = $(this).find("#shadowbottom");
            if (scrollValue == 0) {
                shadowTop.fadeOut(200);
            } else if (scrollValue == ($(this).get(0).scrollWidth - $(this).width())) {
                shadowBottom.fadeOut(200);
            } else {
                shadowTop.fadeIn(200);
                shadowBottom.fadeIn(200);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Check this fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/usu4enev/3/

Comment: You're not addressing the actual problem, _duplicate ids_. Instead, you're showing escape path.

Comment: Thanks very much for all the help guys. I know the duplicate IDs are an issue, unfortunately I've only recently been assigned to this particular project and not really in a position to make too many amends to the existing code. I'm told that it was written with duplicate IDs for a reason, but unfortunately that's the extent of the explanation I got.

Comment: This is almost perfect. The only remaining problem is as follows. I need it to detect if each container named "data-holder" has scrollable content on load (it's for mobile), and if so, to add the right shadow to the scrollable containers (as an indicator that there is scrollable content - as mobiles don't show scrollbars). I tried adding something like the following to the code but it doesn't work: 

$('.scroll-container').each(function(){ if ($(".scroll-container").prop('scrollWidth') > $(".scroll-container").width() ) { var shadowRight = $(this).find(".shadow-right"); shadowRight.show(); }

Comment: Can anyone please advise as to how I would get the right side shadows to appear on page load for the divs that have scrollable content? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the updates guys. It's working perfectly now. As it turns out it was working in JSFiddle but not on the actual website until I changed $(document).ready(function() to $(window).load(function(), but I ended up having to use a setInterval function. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nahfzgxe/1/
I'm now left with one last issue. When I resize the browser window until the scrollbars are no longer visible the right side shadow remains.This particular fiddle doesn't work but it works on my website (unfortunately I can't provide the actual URL as it hasn't been released yet.